# Groovy execution time is too slow in CAS 7.0.0-RC9.BUG?

Tags: groovy, cas

I have got problem with long execution time of basic groovy script:

cas.propierties:

```
cas.authn.attribute-repository.groovy[0].location=file:/etc/cas/config/custom-attr.groovy
```

custom-attr.groovy:

```
import java.util.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import groovy.transform.Field
import javax.naming.directory.*
import java.util.Hashtable
import javax.naming.*

@Field File file = new File("/etc/cas/config/groovy_logs.txt")


def run(final Object... args) {
    def (username,attributes,logger,properties,appContext) = args
    logger.debug("[{}]: The received uid is [{}]", this.class.simpleName, username)

    file.append "\n login: "+args[0]+" cas-id:"+args[1]['principal']+"\n"
    file.append "\n version groove: "+GroovySystem.version+"\n"


    // All attribute values must be defined as a collection wrapped in []
    return [username:[username], likes:["6cheese", "7food"], id:[1234,2,3,4,5], another:["attribute"] ]


    println GroovySystem.version
}
```

System CAS params has been showed after startup :

```
CAS Version: 7.0.0-RC9
CAS Branch: master
CAS Commit Id: xxxxxxxxxxx
CAS Build Date/Time: 2023-11-25T07:12:15.881468Z
Spring Boot Version: 3.2.0
Spring Version: 6.1.0
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/zulu21-ca-amd64
Java Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc.
Java Version: 21.0.1
Servlet Version: 6.0.0
JVM Free Memory: 345 MB
JVM Maximum Memory: 4 GB
JVM Total Memory: 512 MB
OS Architecture: amd64
OS Name: Linux
OS Version: 5.4.0-167-generic
OS Date/Time: 2023-12-12T10:35:50.786113719
OS Temp Directory: /tmp
```

Logs:

```
2023-12-12 10:41:41,731 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.attribute.PrincipalAttributeRepositoryFetcher] - <Fetching person attributes for query [{principal=xxxxxx  data xxxxxxx}]>

no activity in the log (just waiting )


2023-12-12 10:41:55,497 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.resolvers.InternalGroovyScriptDao] - <[custom-attr]: The received uid is [christmas_banny]>

2023-12-12 10:41:55,497 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.resolvers.InternalGroovyScriptDao] - <Groovy-based attributes found are [{username=[christmas_banny], likes=[6cheese, 7food], id=[1234, 2, 3, 4, 5], another=[attribute]}]>
```

This problem has occurred only when we attached groovy without groovy authentication work smooth. Groovy is slow or wait  but after  let say 15sek returned additional metadata.What is the problem  or where find out solution of 15sek timeout ?

To eliminate 15sek .

Comment: Is this only the very first time or always? 15s could be DNS or connection timeouts in general. Also there are some odd choices inside the script, which I doubt are the culprit, but I'd get rid of them anyway: don't write to /etc especially if your logging seems to work, remove the unused imports, destructuring args but later not using it consistently, print after return

Comment: It is always about  between 10 to 15 sec  . 10sec  for  docerized  cas , 5sec  for not docerized . Our basic script doesn't use any url or connection to other services / web pages etc. During this timeout  i haven't noticed any blocked or unanswered packages via tcpdump

Answer (score 0):

> Is this only the very first time or always?
> It is always more than 10sec  for contenerized cas or 5 sec for not contenerized  cas .  5sec or 10sec is too much .It should be ms .
> For this basic script we don't have any connection to other services

I have made dipper digging in TRACE  mode seted in cas.properties  and i found out that problem can be "*creating groovy object instannce*"

cas logs:

2023-12-13 11:03:36,183 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.util.scripting.ScriptingUtils] - <Creating groovy object instance from class [/etc/cas/config/custom-attr.groovy]>

```
time out 14sek
```

2023-12-13 11:03:50,884 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.util.scripting.ScriptingUtils] - <Executing groovy script's [run] method, with parameters [[test, {principal=[test], credentialId=[test], credentialClass=[UsernamePasswordCredential], username=[test]}, org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger@3e812f4a, org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties@646427f7, org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2e6d76ba, started on Wed Dec 13 10:55:27 GMT+01:00 2023, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@30af7377]]>
2023-12-13 11:03:50,897 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.resolvers.InternalGroovyScriptDao] - <[custom-attr]: The received uid is [test]>
2023-12-13 11:03:50,898 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.resolvers.InternalGroovyScriptDao]